# Alternative for RWeka in R

Tags: r, text

I'm unable to install RWeka in R under Mac. It returns error Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'RWeka' had non-zero exit status
Searched earlier thread yet couldn't get it working.

What are the alternative to RWeka to incorporate ngram in DTM in R?

Answer (score 0):

`RWeka` is an interface to the `Weka` Java library. You don't need it to generate a document term matrix (DTM). The `tm` package is quite useful for what you are looking to do.

Specifically, check out the [DocumentTermMatrix](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/139244_a5629dbf418f465ab825c063f22535d5.html) function and the [tm vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf).

If you would like other Java interfaces, feel free to try the following:

1. `rJava`
2. `openNLP`

They may be of use if you require links to Java packages.

Comment: thanks, I explored openNLP yet couldn't figure out how to use it to implement bigram

Comment: try the `tm` package and you should be okay, leave some more information if you think you still have issues